# How to select the powers of x termwise based on the results of its mod 3 in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a polynomial in x, for example,

```
x^4/s +  x^3 + x^2*s + x^3*s^2 + x
```

What I want to do is:
based on the result of (the exponent of x) mod 3,

```
   if it's 0, change the x^* to 1;  
   if it's 1, change the x^* to 2;  
   if it is 2, change x^* to 3.
```

So I want to get:

x^4 => 2

x^3 => 1

x^2 => 3

x^1 => 2

therefore, for the given example, I get

```
2/s+1+3s+s^2+2
```

How to do this programmably? Thanks!

Comment: In your example the coeff for x^3 is (1+s^2) ... what are you doing with that?

Comment: I think I don't understand **"based on the result of the exponent of x with 3,..."**

Comment: yes, but that is the same as having 1+s^2.

Comment: hope now it is clear. Sorry for the previous vague meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
(x^4/s + x^3 + x^2*s + x^3*s^2 + x) /. x^(a : _ : 1) :> (Mod[a, 3] + 1)
```

seems to do it.

Edit: Answering the comment:

```
In[4]:= (x^4/s + x^3 + x^2*s + x^3*s^2 + x) /. 
    x^(a : _ : 1) :> (Mod[a, 3] /. {0 :> m, 1 :> n, 2 :> p})


Out[4]= m + n + n/s + p s + m s^2
```

Comment: what if I have another correspondence rule, i.e.    if it's 0, change the x^* to m;  
   if it's 1, change the x^* to n;  
   if it is 2, change x^* to p.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin: thanks a lot. Sorry for continuing asking. What about substituting x^n with another functional evaluation f[n]?

Comment: @Qiang Li: The answer is even simpler then - the rule will be `x^(n : _ : 1) :> f[n]`

Comment: @Qiang I understand your desire to make more questions on the comments based on the previous answers, but that is not the way SO works. I you do so, the new questions are not indexed and are useless for incoming users. I suggest to put another question and/or edit your original one.

Comment: @belisarius: what does SO mean?

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin: the following seems weird : (x^4 x^2/s) /. x^(a : _ : 1) -> (Mod[a, 3] + 1) vs. (x^4 x^2/s) /. x^(a : _ : 1) :> (Mod[a, 3] + 1)

Comment: @Qiang SO -> StackOverflow -> This site :D

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin: also would you please explain the pattern a : _ : 1? thanks

Comment: @Qiang a:_ is the same as a_ . And a:_:1 tells Mma to use a default value 1 when a is absent

Comment: @belisarius: Thanks. I am confused at this line (x^4 x^2/s) /. x^(a : _ : 1) -> (Mod[a, 3] + 1) vs. (x^4 x^2/s) /. x^(a : _ : 1) :> (Mod[a, 3] + 1). To me (x^4 x^2/s) /. x^(a : _ : 1) -> (Mod[a, 3] + 1) should give me 2*3/s=6/s, but I got 2/s. Do you know why, thanks?

Comment: @Qiang: `x^4 * x^2` evaluates into `x^6` even before the rule is applied. Try `Unevaluated[(x^4 x^2/s)] /. x^(a : _ : 1) :> (Mod[a, 3] + 1)` to see the difference

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin: but I thought : will delay the substitution, will it? Also note the different results the two returned. How do you explain the diff, please?

Comment: @Qiang: I don't get different results. Check if you had your `a` defined before globally - that might explain it. As to why Unevaluated etc, I agree with belisarius (as far as I can understand the logic of SO, I am pretty new here) - you probably have to make it another question. Also, sorry, but I am off for today - it is more than 5 a.m. here :)